# Is it possible to write a function that receives itself as parameter?

Tags: c, recursion

I was thinking, you can pass a function to a function as function pointer like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void loop(void(*f)(), int n){
    if(f == NULL)
        printf("is this cursed use of recursion?\n");
    else{
        f();
        if(n == 0)
            loop(NULL, n);
        else
            loop(f, n - 1);
        return;
    }
}
void f(){
    printf("hello world\n");
}
int main(){
    loop(f, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

So a thing came to my mind, is it actually possible to do a function that in some way receives itself as parameter in C?

Comment: this is called recursion.  Your example won't work.  When n is zero it will keep calling itself and blow up the stack.  You will have a stack overflow.  You came to the right place.

Comment: @Hogan It works.:)

Comment: aparent aditing a clause like ```if(loop == f) printf("cursed\n"); else f();``` makes it works even calling itself.

Comment: This code is fine, It's not what the question is about anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look:

```
int f(void (*p)(void), int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    int (*g)(void (*)(void), int) = p;
    return 2 + g(p, n - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    void (*p)(void) = f;
    return f(p, 3);
}
```

<sup>*Note: I wrote it like this for clarity -- if you want to remove warnings about incompatible pointer types, you need to cast explicitly the pointers.*</sup>

The following program's return code is `6`, i.e. `3` multiplied by `2`. As you can see, we are passing `f` to itself explicitly in `main()`, i.e. `f(f, 3)`.

What happens inside `f` itself is even funnier, because `f` is calling `f` with `f` as the argument (although `f` does not know that).

Comment: Conversions between function pointers are defined, at least so that, if you convert back, the result equals the original pointer. So make the argument a function pointer instead of `void *`, then convert it to the desired function type, and the behavior will be defined by the C standard.